# VBA: loop with INDEX MATCH won't go to next value

Tags: vba, excel, loops

VBA-newbie here... Any help appreciated :)

I have a table like this one :

```
S/N     UNIQREF   REF   OPE
ABC123             10    C1
ABC123             20    C2
ABC123             30    I1
ABC123             40    IM1
DEF456             10    C1
DEF456             20    I1
DEF456             30    DR1
HIJ789             10    C1
HIJ789             20    DR1
HIJ789             30    I1
HIJ789             40    XX1
```

...and I need to fill the UNIQREF column.

The rule is: loop through my S/N (serial number) column, and as long as it stays the same, lookup the value on the left of the "I1" OPE (operation), and write it in the UNIQREF in all rows.

For example, we take ABC123, lookup "I1" in OPE, see that the value next to it (on the left) is 30, so we write 30 in the UNIQREF column for all ABC123 S/Ns.

Similarly, we would write 20 for all DEF456 S/Ns, and 30 for all HIJ789 S/Ns.

So far, here is my code:

```
Public Sub routine()

Dim gamWAL as Worksheet
Set gamWAL = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("gamWAL")

i = 3 'because data in my table starts on line 3, line 2 is columns titles and line 1 is comments. Also starts in Column B (my S/N column)...

Do While gamWAL.Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" 'i want the loop to stop at the when the S/N list is over

    Do While gamWAL.Cells(i, "B").Value = gamWAL.Cells(i + 1, "B").Value

        gamWAL.Cells(i, "E").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(gamWAL.Range("F" & i & ":G3000"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("I1", gamWAL.Range("G" & i & ":G3000"), 0), 1)

        i = i + 1

    Loop

Loop

End Sub
```

The issue: it does write "20" for all ABC123 S/Ns, except for the last one, and then doesn't go on to the next "group" of S/Ns... the macro keeps "computing" though (for super long, as the table is currently 900 rows, but is expected to grow to about 4000 rows)..

Any tips on making this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
=INDEX(C:C, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($2:$12)/((A$2:A$12=A2)*(D$2:D$12="I1")), 1))
```

[image]

Assuming that REF is numeric and I1 is unique to each S/N then SUMIFS would do as well and is more versatile and friendly to record deletions/additions.

```
=sumifs(c:c, a:a, a2, d:d, "I1")
```

Comment: That is some serious voodoo.

Comment: Good thinking on the SUMIFs too.

Comment: The sumifs stuff is voodoo. It works like a charm! Care to explain (in plain english) what it actually does?? Because i don't understand what we're sum'ing.. Thanks a million though!

Comment: You're 'summing' a single number; specifically the single number in the row where column D is I1 and column A matches whatever is in column A.

Answer (score 2):

Another formula approach, though no doubt less efficient than Jeeped's as it's an array formula (use Ctrl+Enter+Shift which will make the curly brackets appear).

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$12,MATCH(1,IF($A$2:$A$12=$A2,IF($D$2:$D$12="I1",1)),0))
```

[image]

There is a non-array variation, see http://www.xl-central.com/lookup-multiple-criteria.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible VBA solution, going through 2 steps and using replace.

Step 1:

- loop through all the cells in `Range("A1:A13")` and see whether the value of column `D` is `I1`. If this is the case, write the value from the Reference column, otherwise write the same value as in the SN.
- This is what you get from the first step:

[image]

Step 2:

- loop through the same range and whenever the `UNIQREF` is the same, carry out a replacement.
- The replacement should be only carried out in the `UNIQREF` column.

[image]

Here is the code for the both steps:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim startCell As Long: startCell = 2
    Dim endCell As Long: endCell = 13

    Dim cnt As Long, cnt2 As Long
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim lookFor As String: lookFor = "I1"
    Dim wks As Worksheet: Set wks = Worksheets(1)

    For cnt = startCell To endCell
        Set myCell = wks.Cells(cnt, 1)
        If myCell.Offset(, 3) = lookFor Then
            myCell.Offset(, 1) = myCell.Offset(, 2)
        Else
            myCell.Offset(, 1) = myCell
        End If
    Next cnt

    For cnt = startCell To endCell
        Set myCell = wks.Cells(cnt, 1)
        If myCell <> myCell.Offset(, 1) Then
            wks.Range(wks.Cells(startCell, 2), wks.Cells(endCell, 2)).Replace _
                What:=myCell, Replacement:=myCell.Offset(, 1), LookAt:=xlPart
        End If
    Next cnt

End Sub
```